# O365 SharePoint - mapping drive on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, sharepoint, office365

I would like to map an Office 365 SharePoint site as a drive on my Mac.

Instructions say to use Finder > Go > Connect to Server, and enter the SharePoint site URL, like "https://mysite.sharepoint.com"

When I try this, I get "There was an error connecting to the server".

I can't seem to find an answer to this online.

Any help would be much appreciated.